# Gradle jar task deprecation warning not clear

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle script with a `jar` task configured like so:

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes('Specification-Title': 'RSyntaxTextArea',
      'Automatic-Module-Name': 'org.fife.RSyntaxTextArea', // jdk 9+ module name
      'Specification-Version': version,
      'Implementation-Title': 'org.fife.ui',
      'Implementation-Version': version,
      'Bundle-License': 'BSD-3-Clause',
      // Not sure why Require-Capability is not being added by the osgi plugin...
      'Require-Capability': 'osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=' + javaVersion + '))"')
  }
}
```

As of gradle 8, I get the following warning when building with `--warning-mode all`:

```
The AbstractTask.getConvention() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#deprecated_access_to_conventions
```

The doc linked does not give any explicit advice about `jar` task changes. It *does* provide examples of changes for configuring `war` and `ear` tasks, but the changes suggested (essentially, configuration is done via properties in a closure rather than "convention properties") already seems to be the pattern I'm following with my configuration of `jar`.

I'm honestly completely at a loss as to how to understand what change I need to make. Examples of configuring a jar manifest online seem to mimic what I have here. Any suggestions as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is not related to your `jar` task configuration, but instead referring to [Deprecated access to plugin conventions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#deprecated_access_to_conventions).

Either of the following is true for the deprecation warning to appear:

1. You have somewhere in your Gradle build where you are using/calling plugin conventions.
2. You are using a third-party ([not core Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugin_reference.html)) plugin which is using/calling plugin conventions.

   - To figure out if a plugin is using deprecated functionality, you can remove/disable the plugin and see if the warning persists.

Comment: Thank you! I thought this wasn't the case due to addressing other very similar deprecation warnings with syntax changes (and the fact that the error message is far from helpful :P). Looks like the issue is the `biz.aQute.bnd.gradle` plugin, fixed in an unreleased version - https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues/5714